# Load images from file c#

Tags: c#

this is my code this is showing only one image data multiple times in list view instead of showing all images data.

```
public void loadImages()
{
    string[] liness = File.ReadAllLines("Food.txt");
    for (int a = 0; a < liness.Length; a++)
    {
        string[] check = liness[a].Split(',');
        listView.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var line in liness)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(check[2]);
            listView.Items.Add(item);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you arent asking.  there doest appear to be any code dealing with any kind of images

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 basically check[2] is the index of images saved in file

Comment: @HanzalaIqbal `listView.Items.Clear();` You are clearing listview in each loop iteration. Put `listView.Items.Clear();` line out of loop.

Comment: @HanzalaIqbal Also there is no need of `foreach (var line in liness)` inner loop. Remove this foreach loop.

Comment: @GaurangDave thankyou i have done this so far but nothing happened the actual problem is in foreach loop.

Comment: @GaurangDave removing foreach loop only shows one item in list view that is the last one i added

Comment: @HanzalaIqbal Try this : `public void loadImages()
{
 listView.Items.Clear();
 
 string[] liness = File.ReadAllLines("Food.txt");
 
 for (int a = 0; a < liness.Length; a++)
 {
  string[] check = liness[a].Split(',');
  
  ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(check[2]);
  listView.Items.Add(item); 
 }
}`

Comment: Images can be stored in text files?

Comment: @GaurangDave thankyouso much it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are clearing listview in each loop iteration. Put `listView.Items.Clear();` line out of loop. Also there is no need of `foreach (var line in liness)` inner loop. Remove this foreach loop.

Try this

```
public void loadImages()
{
    listView.Items.Clear();

    string[] liness = File.ReadAllLines("Food.txt");

    for (int a = 0; a < liness.Length; a++)
    {
        string[] check = liness[a].Split(',');

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(check[2]);
        listView.Items.Add(item);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to delete entire row that when i select list view item and press delete it can delete that data from file

Comment: You need to get the selected ListViewItem and then you can remove it from `listView.Items.Remove(item); ` . I suggest you to create new question if you get any other doubt.